# Java Swing Component disappears when I export my project

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, gridbaglayout

I have a java project that use java swing GUI for user interface and every thing is OK when I run my project from eclipse, but when I export my project into an executable jar file, some components are not in my frame(two panel with gridBagLayout are disappeared).

what should I do? I want to export my project :(

Comment: Do you load any images/resources in those panels (e.g. JLabel with icon)? Maybe these reources are present only in Eclipse classpath but not in exported jar.

Comment: Do you run all your Swing code on the EDT ? Do you call `setVisible( true )` after adding all components to the `Container`, or do you correctly invalidate if that's not the case ?

Comment: See also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: I have buttons with images, so how can solve this problem?

Comment: I put all images into one folder(eclipse show it as package) in my project folder